# Can I get id of the binding element from inside the model?

Tags: knockout.js

I am having the following problem. I would like to get the id of the binding from inside of the model. I know that it might be hard to understand what I want (or may be I put that in the wrong words), so here is an example.

```
ko.applyBindings(new Model, document.getElementById('myID'));

function ErrorViewModel() {
    this.foo = function(){
        // do something to output myID
    }
}
```

After reading documention and a quick googling I was not able to find anything. Is it possible?

Comment: Could you clarify what "do something" is?  One of the key points of knockout is avoiding DOM manipulation (separating the view and the view model).  Usually, there's a "knockout"-way of doing things that avoids DOM manipulation.

Comment: Actually I want to hide the element. Thanks for looking into the problem.

Comment: If you know `myID` at first, why do you want to get it inside the model? why not to store it globally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to hide an element, create an observable that will contain your boolean flag and bind it to your DOM element with the "visible" binding:

NOTE: This is not a complete view model, just sample code of setting up your observables:

```
this.isError = ko.observable(false);

<div data-bind='visible: isError'>
    Error message
</div>
```

Now, whenever the "isError" flag is set to true, the error message appears.  When it's false, it's hidden.  You could even vary the message by adding another observable:

```
this.isError = ko.observable(false);
this.errorMessage = ko.observable('Error Message');

<div data-bind='visible: isError, text: errorMessage'>
</div>
```

Now simply set your error message (`this.errorMessage('Name is too short')`) and display it with `this.isError(true)`.